# How to get the code in html Links on UILabel in Swift

Tags: html, swift, hyperlink, uilabel

I have to make several html links on textLabel in TableViewCell. And if
 a user touches a link, I must get the code in the link  and send it other
function.

I made several links  on textLabel in TableViewCell like this:

```
let myText = "The Code of this Doc: <a href=code:1234>1234</a>. The Code
of that Doc : <a href=code:4567>4567</a>. If you touch code number, you can see more information."

let attrString = try! NSMutableAttributedString(data:
myText.dataUsingEncoding(NSUnicodeStringEncoding, allowLossyConversion:
true)!, options: [ NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute:
NSHTMLTextDocumentType], documentAttributes: nil)

textLabel.attributedText = attrString
```

But I don't know how to get the code in the link that a user touched on.
Please help me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit unclear as to the specifics of what you are asking.  Does each individual table cell have a different code?  If so:

Store the text in an array when you create it.  Have the cells grab the text by using:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
   let code = nameOfArray[indexPath.row]
}
```

If you mean that you want to have different codes in the same cell then I would recommend using buttons inside the cell and setting the title of the button to whatever you wish it to be.

Comment: Thanks, but I want to have many different codes in the same cell. And the codes are not determined. The codes are coming from database file dynamically.